# Why does the iOS simulator freeze when selecting another option?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a shopping app with 4 categories: Save money, promotions, deals and coupons. When I do Filter>Select category>Next, the app stops responding and this message shows up.

```
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value  (lldb)
```

And saying the error is on this line:

```
    var geturl: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)! 
    // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode0x0)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqFS7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8coPw.png

Comment: Probably NSURL couldn't make an url from your string so it is nil, and it crashes because you force unwrap it. See [in the Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) how to deal with Optionals (you need to safely unwrap the value).

Answer (score 0):

Try unwrap value

```
            let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: imageURL)

            if let imageURL = url {
                let option = SDWebImageOptions(0)
                SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadImageWithURL (imageURL, options: option, progress: nil, completed: completionBlock)

            } else {
                finishedBlock (nil)
            }
```